# MVC Fill a new model with two tables and display it on the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables:
Product, and ProductReserved.

Product:

```
public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseDescription { get; set; }
    public string SaleDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SalePrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CostPrice { get; set; }
    public string TypeCategory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuantityOnPurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PurchaseOrderArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string Bin { get; set; }
    public string PictureLink { get; set; }
```

ProductReserved:

```
public int ProductReservedID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SellerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuantityReserved { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProductReservedDate { get; set; }
```

I have created a model MainTable with field of both.

```
public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string SaleDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SalePrice { get; set; }
    public string TypeCategory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuantityReserved { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SellerID { get; set; }
```

Now I have problem in the Controller when I want to fill up the new model MainTable. I was trying something like this: (I know is wrong and that is why I need help)

```
MainTable prod = (from p in db.Products
                    join pr in db.ProductReserveds on p.ProductID equals pr.ProductID
                    select new
                    {
                        BarCode = p.BarCode,
                        SaleDescription = p.SaleDescription,
                        SalePrice = p.SalePrice,
                        TypeCategory = p.TypeCategory,
                        QuantityReserved = pr.QuantityReserved,
                        SellerID = pr.SellerID
                    }
            );
```

Also, How I should return this view, and how I should received it on the view??

Comment: Why is this "wrong"?  As long as your view accepts a model of type IEnumerable<MainTable> this should work fine.

Comment: This is wrong with the "JOIN": Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<InthingThree.Models.MainTable>' to 'InthingThree.Models.MainTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
 And it is driving me crazy!

Comment: Your variable needs to be `IEnumerable<MainTable>`, the LINQ query will return multiple objects. You should also probably add a `.ToList()` to your query (after the closing paren) to realize the query so you don't pass an `IQueryable` to your view.

Comment: Craig W., you are da man!!!!

I just add ""List<MainTable> prod ="" and .ToList(); at the end and works!!!!! 
If you put the same thing on the bottom let me give you the credit as the right answer!